# How to customize the header of bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my site, I think the black header is not good and the font is too small. How to customize the header of bootstrap ? Is there any example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to just override the class/id.

Declare the bootstrap first then your own css

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in your mystyle.css you can:

```
header,.header,#header{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```